# How can i deploy docker cluster for many instances via web interface?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a several instances of my application, like dev stand, test stand, demo stand and several production stands. My application is a cluster of microservices, packaged in docker container and managed by docker-compose. I need an ability to conveniently deploy some versions of application to several stands.

**My question is: What tools should i pick for this feature?** Ideally i want to have web interface which has one button “Deploy” for one stand and an input field for a version of my application.

We use Teamcity for building applications, and we can use it for continuous delivery, but i am looking for a more convenient and specialized tool.

Answer (score 1):

We're using Octopus Deploy in our CI process for deployments (releases created by TeamCity) and we're really happy with this tool. 
Although I'm not much into container/Docker things, but i saw that recently Octopus has implemented some features for [Docker deployments](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Docker+Containers) so you could check that maybe. ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer! I thought Octopus Deploy only for .NET. I will try it for docker and linux. May be you have experience with Octopus and Docker?

Comment: Nope, haven't tried it yet! ;)  Just noticed some activity recently about this topic in [Octopus' blog](https://octopus.com/blog?search=docker)